# how to create loops with multi relation taxanomy queries in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to create a loop that loads posts from a custom taxonomy and a specific category , i have used this code below but it doesn't show anything

```
<ul class="row">
    <?php 
        $latest_apps = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => array('product','post'),
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => array( get_option("free_apps_category") )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => array( get_option("premium_apps_category") )
                    )
            )
        ));
        $c = 0;
        while ($latest_apps->have_posts()) : $latest_apps->the_post();
        $c++;

        // post is even
        if( $c % 2 == 0) {
            ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" data-titty="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail("post"); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }

        // post is odd
        else {

        ?>
            <li class="content-box-post">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" data-titty="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail("post"); ?></a>
        <?php
        }
        endwhile;
    ?>
    </ul>
```

i have used static id numbers instead of get_option('free_apps_category') and get_option('premium_apps_category') but it still does not work 
please help , thank u so much 
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not show you nothing, it is because you have no posts that match your condition. 
And reading the code fast One can see that your query is for a post either normal or under `product` post type  that is both on the `premium_apps_category` AND `free_apps_category` . Are you sure that you actually have one ?

Comment: yes actually when i use one of these taxonomies ( category or product_cat) alone it works fine and loads the posts but when i use both taxonomies together it doesn't show anything

Comment: @farscode so like i said .. just make sure you have the categories right or drop the relation `AND`

Comment: I'm sorry i was miss-understanding the meaning of 'AND' , i changed it to 'OR' and now it's working fine , thanks for spending time :)